# Issues with annotations Valid/Regex/Order By, using Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm updating a website from Symfony 1.x to Symfony 2.1 during my internship, and i have some issues with Doctrine's Annotations. Btw i'm kinda newbie in Symfony2.

I meet this type of exception :

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("[Semantical Error] The annotation "@Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\OrderBy" in
>   property IHQS\NuitBlancheBundle\Entity\SC2Profile::$games does not
>   exist, or could not be auto-loaded.") in
>   "/var/www/sites/nuitblanche1/src/IHQS/NuitBlancheBundle/Resources/views/News/archives.html.twig".

And my code is:

```
<?php

namespace IHQS\NuitBlancheBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="IHQS\NuitBlancheBundle\Model\SC2ProfileRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="player")
 */
class SC2Profile
{
    const SC2RACE_PROTOSS = "protoss";
    const SC2RACE_TERRAN  = "terran";
    const SC2RACE_ZERG    = "zerg";
    const SC2RACE_RANDOM  = "random";

    static public $_sc2races = array(
        self::SC2RACE_PROTOSS   => self::SC2RACE_PROTOSS,
        self::SC2RACE_TERRAN    => self::SC2RACE_TERRAN,
        self::SC2RACE_ZERG  => self::SC2RACE_ZERG,
        self::SC2RACE_RANDOM    => self::SC2RACE_RANDOM
    );

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="sc2", cascade={"persist"})
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    protected $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $sc2Role;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Assert\Regex("/\d+/")
     */
    protected $sc2Id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $sc2RanksId;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $sc2Account;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @Assert\Choice(callback = "getSC2Races")
     */
    protected $sc2Race;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     * @Assert\Regex("/\d+/")
     */
    protected $sc2ProfileEsl;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     * @Assert\Regex("/\d+/")
     */
    protected $sc2ProfileSc2cl;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $sc2ProfilePandaria;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $sc2Ranks;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Team", mappedBy="players")
     */
    protected $teams;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="GamePlayer", mappedBy="player")
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"id" = "DESC"})
     */
    protected $games;

    protected $stats;

    protected $statsInit = false;

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getUser() {
        return $this->user;
    }

    public function setUser(User $user) {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function getUsername() {
        return $this->user->getUserName();
    }

    public function getSc2Role() {
        return $this->sc2Role;
    }

    public function setSc2Role($sc2Role) {
        $this->sc2Role = $sc2Role;
    }

    public function getSc2Id() {
        return $this->sc2Id;
    } 

    public function setSc2Id($sc2Id) {
        $this->sc2Id = $sc2Id;
    }

    public function getSc2RanksId()
    {
         return $this->sc2RanksId;
    }

    public function setSc2RanksId($sc2RanksId)
    {
        $this->sc2RanksId = $sc2RanksId;
    }

    public function getSc2Account() {
        return $this->sc2Account;
    }

    public function setSc2Account($sc2Account) {
        $this->sc2Account = $sc2Account;
    }

    public function getSc2Race() {
        return $this->sc2Race;
    }

    public function setSc2Race($sc2Race) {
        if(!in_array($sc2Race, SC2Profile::$_sc2races))
        {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Invalid parameter "' . $sc2Race . '" for StarCraft 2 Race');
        }
        $this->sc2Race = $sc2Race;
    }

    public function getSc2ProfileEsl() {
        return $this->sc2ProfileEsl;
    }

    public function setSc2ProfileEsl($sc2ProfileEsl) {
        $this->sc2ProfileEsl = $sc2ProfileEsl;
    }

    public function getSc2ProfileSc2cl() {
        return $this->sc2ProfileSc2cl;
    }

    public function setSc2ProfileSc2cl($sc2ProfileSc2cl) {
        $this->sc2ProfileSc2cl = $sc2ProfileSc2cl;
    }

    public function getSc2ProfilePandaria() {
        return $this->sc2ProfilePandaria;
    }

    public function setSc2ProfilePandaria($sc2ProfilePandaria) {
        $this->sc2ProfilePandaria = $sc2ProfilePandaria;
    }

    public function getGames() {
        $games = $this->games;

        $result = array();
        foreach($games as $game)
        {
            $result[] = $game->getGame();
        }
        return $result;
    }

    public function getWarGames()
    {
        $warGames = array();
        foreach($this->getGames() as $game)
        {
            $wg = $game->getWarGame();
            if($wg instanceof WarGame)
            {
                $warGames[$wg->getId()] = $wg;
            }
        }

        return $warGames;
    }

    public function getReplays() {
        $games = $this->games;

        $result = array();
        foreach($games as $game)
        {
            if(!$game->getGame())               { continue; }
            if(!$game->getGame()->getReplay())  { continue; }

            $result[] = $game->getGame();
        }

        return $result;
    }

    public function getStats()
    {
        if($this->statsInit) { return $this->stats; }

        $this->initStatsVariables();

        $counter = 0;
        foreach($this->getWarGames() as $game)
        {
            $team2 = false;
            foreach($game->getTeam2() as $p2)
            {
                if($p2->getPlayer() && $p2->getPlayer()->getId() == $this->getId()) { $team2 = true; break; }
            }
            if($team2) { continue; }


            $type = "_" . $game->getType();

            if($game->getTeam1Result() == Game::RESULT_WIN)     { $this->stats[$type]["wins"]++; }
            if($game->getTeam1Result() == Game::RESULT_LOSS)    { $this->stats[$type]["losses"]++; }

            if($game->getType() == Game::TYPE_1v1)
            {
                $type = $type.$game->getTeam2Race();
                if($game->getTeam1Result() == Game::RESULT_WIN)     { $this->stats[$type]["wins"]++; }
                if($game->getTeam1Result() == Game::RESULT_LOSS)    { $this->stats[$type]["losses"]++; }
            }
        }

        foreach($this->stats as $type => $data)
        {
            $this->stats[$type]["ratio"] = (($data["losses"] + $data["wins"]) == 0)
                ? 0
                : round(100 * $data["wins"] / ($data["losses"] + $data["wins"]));
        }

        $this->statsInit = true;
        return $this->stats;
    }

    public function initStatsVariables()
    {
        $this->stats = array(
            "_1v1" => array(),
            "_2v2" => array(),
            "_3v3" => array(),
            "_4v4" => array(),
            "_1v1protoss"   => array(),
            "_1v1terran"    => array(),
            "_1v1zerg"      => array(),
            "_1v1random"    => array()
        );

        foreach($this->stats as $type => $data)
        {
            $this->stats[$type] = array(
                "wins"      => 0,
                "losses"    => 0,
                "ratio"     => 0
            );
        }
    }

    public function get2v2Teams()
    {
        $teams = array();

        foreach($this->getWarGames() as $game)
        {
            if($game->getType() != Game::TYPE_2v2)
            {
                continue;
            }

            $team2 = false;
            foreach($game->getTeam2() as $p2)
            {
                if($p2->getPlayer() && $p2->getPlayer()->getId() == $this->getId()) { $team2 = true; break; }
            }
            if($team2) { continue; }

            // looking for ally
            $ally = null;
            $members = $game->getTeam1();
            foreach($members as $member)
            {
                if($member->getName() != $this->getSc2Account())
                {
                    $ally = $member;
                    break;
                }
            }

            // updating hash table
            $key = $ally->getName(). '_' . $ally->getRace();
            if(!isset($teams[$key]))
            {
                $teams[$key] = array(
                    "allyName"  => $ally->getName(),
                    "allyRace"  => $ally->getRace(),
                    "wins"  => 0,
                    "losses"    => 0
                );
            }

            if($game->getTeam1Result() == Game::RESULT_WIN)     { $teams[$key]["wins"]++; }
            if($game->getTeam1Result() == Game::RESULT_LOSS)    { $teams[$key]["losses"]++; }
        }

        foreach($teams as $key => $team)
        {
            $teams[$key]["ratio"] = (($team["losses"] + $team["wins"]) == 0)
                ? 0
                : round(100 * $team["wins"] / ($team["losses"] + $team["wins"]));
        }

        usort($teams, function($a, $b) {
            if($a['wins'] == $b['wins'])
            {
                if($a['losses'] == $b['losses']) { return 0; }
                return $a['losses'] > $b['losses'] ? 1 : -1;
            }

            return $a['wins'] < $b['wins'] ? 1 : -1;
        });
        return $teams;
    }

    public function setSc2Ranks(array $sc2ranks)
    {
        $this->sc2Ranks = serialize($sc2ranks);
    }

    public function getSc2Ranks()
    {
        return unserialize($this->sc2Ranks);
    }

    public function __toString() {
            return $this->getSc2Account();
    }
}
```

And i'm also meetin the same problem with the Constraint/Regex who is not auto-loaded or doesn't exists.Though i have all my doctrine bundles working.
My question is kinda simple : What i'm doing wrong? (I know it's not a very spécific one!)

Comment: Does you `GamePlayer` table have a column called `Id`?

Comment: Yes, all my table have an ID.

Answer (score 1):

The problem doesn't look to be with the `@ORM\OrderBy({"id" = "DESC"})` annotation. That looks correct and you have included `use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;`.

It looks like the problem has to do with the relationship between your `SC2Profile` entity and your `GamePlayer` entity. Are both these entities in the `IHQS\NuitBlancheBundle\Entity` namespace?

You could try updating the relationship to use the fully qualified class name.

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\IHQS\NuitBlancheBundle\Entity\GamePlayer", mappedBy="player")
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"id" = "DESC"})
 */
protected $games;
```

Lastly, ensure that the opposite relationship (`ManyToOne`) has been setup in your `GamePlayer` entity.

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="SC2Profile", inversedBy="games")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="referenced_id")
 */
protected $player;
```